# Getting NaN values when combining 2 DataFrames without any NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, nan

I have 2 data frames, `X_train`, and `label_X_train`. These do not contain any null values.

```
np.any(np.isnan(X_train))
np.any(np.isnan(label_X_train))
```

It returns `False` for both.

However when I join them:

```
finalTrain = X_train.join(label_X_train)
np.any(np.isnan(finalTrain))
```

It returns `True`.

**Note:**

I have tried doing reindex using:

```
label_X_train.reindex(finalTrain.index)
```

`X_train`, and `label_X_train` have 1699 records. After joining, 168 have `NaN` values. All the columns from `label_X_train` have `NaN` value for those 168 records.

I have tried doing an inner join, it gives a data frame of 1531 records (168 NaN values records are not included) I want the data frame of 1699 records as the original 2 data frames have 1699 records and no NaN values.

Answer (score 1):

`join` by default does a left join. To join both the dfs and only retain rows that intersect, you need to do an inner join.
Read more about joins [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/) and the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) on how to do an inner join.

Comment: I have tried doing an inner join, it gives a data frame of 1531 records (168 NaN values records are not included) I want the data frame of 1699 records as the original 2 data frames have 1699 records and no NaN values.